# Using the Clipboard in Win32

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks, clipboard

I've created a small program in Code::Blocks using the Win32API GUI, all written in C++.
I want to add a button to automatically copy the text present in an edit control, how do you do that?

(Note that I'm new to the Win32API)

Comment: Clipboard API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard

Comment: Copy from or to edit control?

Comment: Selecting text of an edit control: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setsel

Comment: To copy the text present in the edit control in the clipboard, so FROM the edit control

Comment: Yes, I did see those pages, but as I said I'm kinda new to Win32, and I was wondering if someone could give me some kind of explanation

Comment: Someone can, indeed. His name is Charles Petzold, and he wrote a [book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X).

Comment: Chapter 12 of Petzold's book is about the clipboard. I also highly recommend that book. Back in the day I started learning the Win32 API here: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/ but that page doesn't explain the clipboard. AFAIK the original DevC++ IDE contained a text editor example application, which implemented clipbord commands: https://www.bloodshed.net/

Comment: For edit control it is easy. Select text with `SendMessage( edit_hwnd, EM_SETSEL, 0, -1 );` then copy it with `SendMessage( edit_hwnd, WM_COPY, 0, 0 );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to associate with the edit control through [`OpenClipboard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-openclipboard), and then call [`SetClipboardData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclipboarddata) to set the clipboard.

Here is a sample:

```
#include <Windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
#define IDB_ONE 3001
HWND edit;
int WINAPI WinMain(_In_  HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_  LPSTR szCmdLine, _In_  int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("hello windows");
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"), szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName,
        TEXT("the hello program"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        edit = CreateWindowW(L"edit", L"test", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE | ES_WANTRETURN | ES_NOHIDESEL, 100, 100, 300, 300, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        HWND btn = CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"copy", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 500, 150, 50, 50, hwnd, (HMENU)IDB_ONE, NULL, NULL);
        return 0;
    }
    break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDB_ONE:
            int len = GetWindowTextLengthW(edit);
            TCHAR buf[1024]{};
            size_t memsize = sizeof(wchar_t) * (len + 1);
            GetWindowTextW(edit, (LPWSTR)buf, len + 1);
            HGLOBAL glob = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, memsize);
            if (glob != NULL)
            {
                void* mem = GlobalLock(glob);
                if (mem != NULL)
                {
                    memcpy(mem, buf, memsize);
                    GlobalUnlock(glob);
                    HANDLE handle = NULL;

                    if (OpenClipboard(edit))
                    {
                        EmptyClipboard();
                        handle = SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, glob);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

It works for me:

[image]

Comment: You can implement auto-selection by sending the EM_SETSEL message to the EDIT control.

Comment: *"You need to associate with the edit control through `OpenClipboard`"* - Er, no, that's not how things work. `OpenClipboard` sets the **owner** of the clipboard to a **thread**. It boggles the mind to see *MSFT* users consistently demonstrate an abundant lack of understanding of the system.

Comment: doesn't work for me, gives me a couple of syntax erros, which I fixed removing __In__ from the arguments in the WinMain function, and changing CreateWindow in line 55 to CreateWindowW. Also when I try to copy it copies some weird chinese characters

Comment: @iKebab897 I have updated my code and you can refer to it.

Comment: Ok, now it works, even though WinMain still gives a syntax error for _In_ and _In_opt_

Comment: @iKebab897 Hi,if this answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I've tried implementing the code, however it results in an awkward glitch whenever I try clicking a button or writing text anywhere. How do I share my code?